# jquery modal form

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I am having an issue with a modal form. I have a text link that opens the modal form(working). Once the form opens it shows a registration page(working). The buttons used to submit the form are through the modal form. For example:

```
$("#register-dialog").dialog({
bgiframe: true,
autoOpen: false,
height: 450,
width: 400,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'Create an account': function() {
            //ajax request here
    }
    }});
```

The buttons are showing up. However, I have discovered an issue with them. If I click on the link that opens the modal form and then click on the cancel button it works fine. I can also click the x at the top and it works fine. But if I click on the "Create an account" button (which performs an ajax request) and then click on the cancel button it does not work anymore. The strange thing about this is that if I click the x at the top it closes it. But there is something even stranger, now the link to open the modal form does not work until I reload the page. The crazy part of all of this is that the ajax request will continue to work. It seems that the ajax request is causing the issues here. All that I am doing with the request is updating the database with there credentials and updating the form to show that they had registered. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to separate the dialog and the buttons initialization codes.

So, I would do the following:

```
$("#register-dialog").dialog({
bgiframe: true,
autoOpen: false,
height: 450,
width: 400,
modal: true
});
```

The form's HTML:

```
<div id="register-dialog">
...
<div id="acceptButton"><a href="#">...</a></div>
</div>
```

And finally the button code like:

```
$("#acceptButton").click(function (event) {
...
});
```

Regards.

Comment: I was going to try that out and see what happens but I wanted to see if anyone had a fix for this or could tell me why it was happening. I also figured something out, there is a close with a dialog. For example:
$("#register-dialog").dialog({
bgiframe: true,
autoOpen: false,
height: 450,
width: 400,
modal: true,
close: function(){
//code here
}
});

In that function if I tell it to reload the modal onclose it seems to fix the issue of it not loading after you submit the form and click the link again.

Comment: Also do you know how to reset the form back to its original state. For example if they fill out the fields and click submit it removes the form and says thanks for registering. Now if they close the form and then open it back up it still shows the message. I want it to go back to its original state with the fields shown. Any ideas?

Comment: In fact, I use to work with my own buttons and I take control of most I can (as you can see), and once the user clicks on the "acceptButton" I submit the data using AJAX and then I check the response for errors. I work with the version 1.3.1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

To clear the form put the following under the success: section of your form submit:

```
document.myForm.reset();
```